# Azure function apps - changing from premium plan to app service plan

Tags: azure, azure-function-app

I have an existing function app that is currently running on a premium plan (EP1 pricing tier). I would like to swap to an app service plan (S1 pricing tier) to hopefully save some budget. I created the new app service plan that I want to swap to, but when I go to change the app service plan of my function app, it doesn't show up in the dropdown menu. Is it possible to change the plan type? Or is this something that can only be set when the function app is created (in which case I suppose I have to recreate/redeploy my function app)?

Answer (score 1):

I believe if the [New App Service is in the same region and resource group as the existing App Service plan this will work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-plan-manage#move-an-app-to-another-app-service-plan).

Comment: Yes, I made sure to put the new app service plan (S1 tier) in the same resource group and region. However, I'm still not seeing it in the dropdown list of app service plans that I can switch to.

Comment: @Michelle i believe  this is not possible .. either switching it  from consumption plan to app service plan nor premium to app serviceplan . since these work totally different in the background. You have to create a new function app with app sevice plan. Hope they comeup with some turnaround for this.